# Thunderbird 3 Global Search

Tags: macos, search, thunderbird

Global search in Thunderbird 3.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 does not work. It is enabled in the preferences.

I am searching on text that is in message bodies or subjects. I have also tried searching on email addresses. Thunderbird searches forever and never shows results. I have tried searching Mozilla knowledge base and forums, but have not found any solutions.

Any suggestions on how solve this, or at least some diagnostics I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I know that when I first installed TB3 I had to leave it "online" or else it wouldn't index.

This add on might help too: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/9873/

Comment: TB3 has been online long enough on my system to have indexed everything. When I open the activity monitor while it is downloading I occasionally see it adding to the index. The add-on looks interesting. I am not sure how to inturprert it. When I search for word in a message that is on disk and has an ID I still do not get results.

Comment: I had similar problems to you, and the forums at TB3 were not much help, so all I can tell you is what worked for me...
The add-on I pasted in can limit the accounts that are indexed.  In my ase I had 4, and only wanted one indexed.  Things started working after I did that AND deleted my global-messages-db.sqlite (the file that stores the indexes).

How big is yours?